# Lagrange Multipliers in practice

Tags: optimization, noise

Say we want to minimize the function $f^2({\bf{x}})$, under the constraint
$g({\bf{x}})=0$.

---

The classic solution (**Method I**) is to introduce a Lagrange Multiplier, and solve:
$$\frac{\partial f^2({\bf{x}})}{\partial x_i}+\lambda \frac{\partial g({\bf{x}})}{\partial x_i}=0$$

One could however use a different method (**Method II**), where we redefine the cost function as:
$$J\equiv f^2({\bf{x}})+\Lambda g^2({\bf{x}})$$
and then we must solve:
$$\frac{\partial f^2({\bf{x}})}{\partial x_i}+\Lambda \frac{\partial g^2({\bf{x}})}{\partial x_i}=0$$
Here $\Lambda$ is a set constant, and is not to be solved for like $\lambda$. Solving leads to a solution that is dependent on $\Lambda$, and is equivalent to method I, when $\Lambda\to\infty$. I think the second method has an advantage when the data is noisy and therefore will not exactly satisfy the constraint, but the choice for $\Lambda$ needs to be made manually.

**Does Method II have a name? is it commonly used? what are the main
pros and cons, other than the ones mentioned?**

Comment: Sounds like you're talking about [penalty methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penalty_method)

Comment: @Glen_b - not quite, since I don't necessarily want the constrained solution.

Comment: It is difficult to see how the second method could yield the correct solution as $\Lambda\to\infty$. As $\Lambda$ grows large, the solutions to $J$ usually would approach minima of $g^2$ alone and ultimately neglect $f$ altogether. Try it, for instance, with $f(x,y)=(x+y)^2$ and $g(x,y)=x+y+1$. The second method produces $x=0$ no matter what value $\Lambda$ might have (and $y\to -1$ as $\Lambda\to\infty$), whereas the minimum of $f$ is attained at $(x,y)=(-1,0)$.